# Nginx and authentication module: How to get the specific statusText from authetication

Tags: authentication, nginx

I'm using nginx and the auth module. Is it possible to get the specific statusText from the subrequest if the authentication fails? I just get `401 Unauthorized`, but not the status header text I return in the authentication request, eg. `401 My own status header message`. I hope I can achieve it somehow by using `auth_request_set` but I could not figure out how. This is part of my nginx configuration:

```
location /session {
  auth_request /auth;
  fastcgi_pass                      unix:/run/fcgi.session.socket;
  fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
  fastcgi_param  URI                $uri;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
}

location /auth {
  fastcgi_pass                      unix:/run/fcgi.user.socket;
  fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
  fastcgi_pass_request_body  off;

  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     "";
  fastcgi_param  HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
  fastcgi_param  URI                $uri;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
}
```